# Phonegap db.transaction callback firing more than once

Tags: javascript, cordova, asynchronous

I am having an issue with a project I am working on using [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/)

*[Step 1]* - 
I am storing a users login "session" locally (Web SQL) from a web server. This is working fine, I can successfully connect to the web server, post the user login data, get a response from the server, create the local User database and store the user "session" value

*[Step 2]* - I then need to pass this "session" value back to the web server, and receive response data from the server. Again, this works as expected but the problem is, **the callback function is being executed twice**.

*Step 2* is called when the user taps a button on the screen, and it doesn't seem like the reason that *Step 2* is being called twice if because phonegap is picking  up the tap more than once, I have tried:

```
$(".yes_sync").live("tap", function(){
    console.log("tap!");
    ...
```

Which only logs a single tap event.

When the user taps I am calling:

```
var db = window.openDatabase("MVIdb", "1.0", "MVIsqlite", 200000);
db.transaction(getUserId, getUserIdFailed, getUserIdsSuccess);
```

The getUserId, getUserIdFailed and getUserIdsSuccess functions look like so:

```
function getUserId(tx){
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '1'", [], getUserIdsSuccess,     getUserIdFailed);
}

function getUserIdFailed(tx, results){
    console.log("Error retrieving user session ID");
}

function getUserIdsSuccess(tx, results){
    console.log("Success retrieving user session ID");
    if(typeof results != 'undefined'){
        var return_value = results.rows.item(0).user_id; 
        user_session_id = return_value;
        var token = $.md5(user_session_id+"whatever!");

        $.get('http://localhost/project/dummyserver/sync?user_id=' + user_session_id + '&token=' + token, function(data) {  
            data = $.parseJSON(data);       
            for (var key in data){
                console.log(data[key]['user_id']);
            }

            $(".ui-loader").fadeOut();
            jQuery.mobile.changePage("_sync_complete.html", {  role: "dialog", transition: "pop" } );
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, the last line in the callback for the $.get in the callback for the success opens a pop up dialogue. This dialogue is being called twice.

I have noticed that phonegap has a lot of asynchronous behaviour, which I understand is to prevent the system from feeling "laggy", but surely it shouldn't be executing a callback function on a db.transaction more than once?

Comment: By the way: It's not Phonegap that is making WebSQL asynchronous – it's always like that, even if you run it in a browser. That's just how it is defined.

Comment: @IngoBürk Interesting. This is my first time using WebSQL, I hardly know anything about it yet, I must definitely do some proper reading up on it

Comment: It takes a bit to get the hang of asynchronous stuff, but it's worth it. ;) Another general thing: If you need the database connection more than once (other buttons or this button being called several times) you might want to consider going to a more global scope with the `window.openDatabase` so you don't have to reopen a connection everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution, but I went with using a global variable

```
var has_getUserIdsSuccess = false;
```

And in the callback function:

```
if(typeof results != 'undefined'){
    if (has_getUserIdsSuccess == false){ 
        has_getUserIdsSuccess = true;
        // as per above
        has_getUserIdsSuccess = false;  // set it back to false so use can press the execute this function again later
    }
```

I am still interested to see if anyone has a better solution!

Answer (score 2):

Your callback is called twice because you are passing it both to the `executeSql` command and the `transaction`. Remove it from one to make it work as expected.

Comment: Nope, still fires more than once

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the `tap` event doesn't somehow fire twice? Some consoles display identical `log` messages as one just with a '2' next to it to indicate that it occured twice. Updating the code (with only one callback) and maybe a bit more of your `tap` event might help, at least I can't spot anything else right now.

Comment: Also, but this is just me, just for testing purposes I would try `click` instead of `tap` and check if it makes a difference.

Comment: By the way, `live` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. Use `on` instead. Also make sure you are attaching the event handler only once -- you wouldn't be the first one to accidentally attach it twice or more often.

Comment: The tap event is definitely only getting fired once. I'll mess around with it when I'm back in at work tomorrow, I'll let you know if I find anything, thanks Ingo